# getting array of non null objects

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java-stream

I have developed following function to get an array of not null objects:

```
private static Object[] getArrayNotNulls(Object... objs) {
    return Arrays.stream(objs).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray();
}
```

Which I am calling like this:

```
Object[] x = getArrayNotNulls(1,2, null, 3);
```

This works fine, however, I was wondering, if there is not already a java method that does the same. Something like:

```
Object[] y = Collections.getArrayNotNull(1,2,null,3)
```

or a mix, I would like to call directly the

```
Object[] y = Arrays.stream(1,2,null,3).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray();
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

but this does not work, since it does not accept Object... arguments

Comment: You should prefer collections classes over arrays as they provide more functionality and there's rarely a need to use an array. Then you could use for example `List.removeIf()` to get rid of nulls, or not add any nulls to the collection in the first place.

Comment: `Arrays.<Object> asList(1, 2, null, 3).stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray();` would achieve the same. Advantage here being that this could be done inline as it takes `null` objects.

Comment: @Kayaman I know, but I need an array, since its the arguments passed to a function i did not develop

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no such method in the JDK. The logical place would be [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) but there's no such method in there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ben comment, **his** solution worked out:

```
Arrays.<Object> asList(1, 2, null, 3).stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray();
```

and I also found out that it can be done little bit cleaner using:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, null, 3).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray();
```

Comment: Or `Stream.of(1, 2, 3).toArray();` or `new Object[] { 1, 2, 3}`. In the end, the solutions of your answer do not differ significantly from the solution of your question. By the way, `<Object>` is obsolete her, you can simply use `Arrays.asList(1, 2, null, 3)`.

Answer (score -2):

I have another solution using lamdas, but it look very Similar to yours

```
Stream.filter(x -> x!=null):
```

There are also a plenty of good solutions if you will use lists: 
[link](http://www.baeldung.com/java-remove-nulls-from-list)

Comment: This just replaces the cleaner method reference with an explicit lambda. It's the same solution, except a bit poorer.